# javascript history - get previous hash

Tags: javascript, history

Is there any way to get the previous hash using the history object ?I now that I can load it using history.back(),but is there any way to access the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
document.referrer
```

It will return the previous url and then you can write a regular expression to get your hash.

Comment: A regular expression for `split`? :o)

Comment: you will be receiving something like this: "http://localhost/page#hash". You can either split it with "#" or use regular expression.

Comment: I meant, there is no need for a regular expression when `split` is more than enough

Comment: document.referrer returns "" for me

Comment: document.referrer can be empty if there was an ajax call.

Comment: is there any way to get the url if there was an ajax call?

Comment: the hash is not part of the referrer.

Comment: @user1217380 "The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, by using a bookmark)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the history obj. back() and store the value inside an array you are manage so you could fetch it when you need it. However, I would recommend you using something like: https://github.com/PaulKinlan/leviroutes that does it for you...

Comment: not really sure how to store the obj in an array.can you please give an example?